# APM Pattern Use a Thread from Threadpool?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I wonder whether existing I/O bound APM calls in .net API (BeginGetResponse, BeginRead, etc.) uses a thread from threadpool or uses the current thread until the callback. I know that it is "async" all the way down to the hardware/network card. I also know that the callback is executed on threadpool. My question is that: All contents of BeginGetResponse are executed on Threadpool or the contents until waiting for I/O are executed on current thread; then the rest is executed on threadpool.

I hope that the question is clear. I really wonder how BeginGetResponse is implemented underhood.

Comment: How about finding it out on your own by using [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net) on the .NET runtime and inspecting the source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APM is more general mechanism.  But the cases you are talking about use the operating system's support for [I/O completion ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The general idea is that your main thread calls the BeginXxx() method.  Under the hood, it calls [ThreadPool.BindHandle()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms223208.aspx), that sets up the plumbing to get the port to automatically start a TP thread when the I/O operation completes.  That thread calls your callback method.

Core idea that *no* thread is waiting while the I/O operation takes place.

This is supported for MessageQueue, FileStream, PipeStream, Socket, FileSystemWatcher, IpcChannel and SerialPort.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about existing APM calls for I/O bound computations. The statements until ThreadPool.BingHandle() is executed on the current thread, right? That's why, it is not immediate non-blocking. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

BeginXxx execute on the current thread. You can easily verify this for yourself using e.g. Reflector. Moreover, sometimes the callback is executed on the current thread too. One case is if an error occurs early, and another is when the actual asynchronous I/O operation blocks — this happens sometimes, as [asynchronous I/O is not *guaranteed* not to block](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/09/23/10215586.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The IAsyncResult approach using worker pool threads is available only for some tasks. Like FileIO (not directory enumeration), LDAP query (v2.0), ADO .net queries.
If you have it and can take the complexity, use the APM. They are usually built by .net folks as it takes some complexity.
Otherwise, use hand built if you think you will get speed.
Using explicit threads gives you more control. Specifically, you can choose to have foreground threads, which will keep your application "alive" after the main thread returns from Main. Explicit threads can also specify their COM threading apartment.
The general rule is to use the threadpool when you have a queue of work items to do, and use an explicit thread when you have an architectural need for them.

Answer (score 0):

Many operations use [IO completion ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

This means that no thread is used while waiting for the operation. Once the operation is complete, the callback is called on a thread-pool thread or using some other synchronization context.